# How to create a pdo mysql prepared statement with a placeholder in a custom equation?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am implementing a rating system that was similar to what you see in google play and many others. To do that, I created a table named `tbl_ratings` and columns `PRIMARY`, `IID` and `sum_rating`. Off course, the `PRIMARY` column is in auto-increment key, the `IID` is the item id and `sum_rating` is the cumulative sum of all user ratings.

So the `tbl_ratings` table can look like this:

```
PRIMARY IID sum_rating
21       2   100
```

Now this is what I intend to do, I want to avoid doing `SELECT` just to retrieve a value for use in PHP, since I can do a simple addition from within an update query, so each time there is a user that submits a rating, I will update the table following this:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tbl_ratings SET sum_rating=sum_rating+".$_POST['rating']." WHERE IID='2'")
$stmt->execute();
```

But of course as you know, this is a bad implementation cause this is open to SQL Injection. But hey it work! So now I want to do it much safer by doing

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tbl_ratings SET sum_rating=sum_rating+? WHERE IID='2'")
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['rating']));
```

If you notice its quite simple, I just replace the potential sql injection point by the `?` placeholder as would a correct prepared statement should be constructed. The Bad Bad thing is, **this does not work**. I tried looking in the web but it seems to be not that fruitful.

What should be the proper way to achieve the calculation of a known column value plus a data in a 1 pdo prepared statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All values convert to string values in execute method. You must use [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php) method to set a value type, for example:

```
$sth->bindParam(1, $_POST['rating'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```